# Can only LinearLayout specify a fixed-size element with an adjacent element that uses the remaining space?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'd like to have two adjacent views, a first that is a fixed size and a second that adjacent to the first that uses the remaining space.

I could easily do this with `LinearLayout` and weights, but I would like to avoid the "nested weights are bad for performance" problem.

Is there another layout type that can accomplish the equivalent?  Please provide an example if so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `RelativeLayout` could do what you want, for example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Button"
        android:background="#99cc00" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button1"
        android:text="Button" 
        android:background="#0077cc"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The first `Button` will be 200dp in width and the second will stretch to fill the rest of the parent's remaining width.

You could also use a `RelativeLayout` to split two views in equal sizes to avoid having double weights on some layouts.

Comment: Very odd, using your code verbatim with the Graphical Layout editor in a file within my project there is a ton of whitespace in the middle, but when I view it from a file within in the API Demos project, it was correct.

Comment: @JeffAxelrod I don't know what you're doing in your projects but my snippet should work with no issues at all. I've used this many times in layouts without any problems.(Also the Graphical layout editor could be a bit problematic sometimes)

Comment: Nothing weird that I know of!  No custom views or anything like that.

Comment: Wait a minute.  Why would `button2` take up any more space than the text `"Button"` plus padding if its `layout_width` is `wrap_content`?

Comment: @JeffAxelrod because it's align right of `button1` and right of `parent view` (relativelayout) which stretch the `button2` from the right of button1 to the right of the parent view. in this case, even when `layout_width="0dp"` it will get stretched.

Comment: @JeffAxelrod The key is the two attributes from the `RelativeLayout`. You say you want the second to be to the right of the first button(to start from button1's right edge) and you also want the view to go until the right edge of the parent. The `RelativeLayout` will make sure that button2 respects those bounds by offering enough space, ignoring what was actually set on that view.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this could be done with a RelativeLayout. Example:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button">
       ...
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="view with fixed size " />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="view with remaining space" />

</LinearLayout>
```

this is how weight works in LinearLayout:

```
At first, it will deduct the fixed dimension, then according to the weight, divide the available space, assign to the views which specify the weight attribute
```

Comment: From the question, `I could easily do this with LinearLayout and weights, but I would like to avoid the "nested weights are bad for performance" problem.`

Comment: then just add android:layout_width="match_parent" for the second view